# Android: Recognising Gestures when screen is locked

Tags: android, gesture

I am currently in the process of creating an MP3 player. In particular, the main mode of user input is in the form of (touchscreen) gestural input. I would like to add the functionality allowing users to continue interacting with the MP3 player when the screen is locked. That is, how can I get the device (A Galaxy S3 in particular if it's worth mentioning) to recognise gestures in the lock screen and "parse" them to the MP3 player?

Note: by "locked" I mean when one can see the lock screen (i.e. not when the screen is turned off).

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way is to make Lock Screen Widgets. These are widgets that allow you to interact with apps in the lockscreen such as the Google Play Music app.

Check out the official tutorial here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen

Comment: Now only for Android version lower than 5